# How to deal with an array of equal values and max function?

Tags: php

In PHP, `max()` returns the highest value in an array or the greatest value among inputs. If we have two or more equally greatest values, how to deal with that situation?
eg

```
$arr = array("a"=>1,"b"=>10, "c"=>10);
```

now, what should `max($arr)`, return. Ideally it returns the first encountered highest value, b. What if I want both b and c as result?

Comment: It doesn't return b or c, it returns the highest value: 10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have the highest value in that array (that is, what max() returns), you can just search for all occurrences of that value in the array:

```
$arrOfKeys = array_keys($arr, max($arr));
```

Comment: +1 for `array_keys()` - this is a much better approach than mine.

Answer (score 3):

`max()` returns the maximum *value*, not the array key it is associated with. It will simply return `(int) 10` in the example you give.

If you want a list of the keys that have the maximum value you could do something like this:

```
$max = max($array);
$maxKeys = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
  if ($val == $max) {
    $maxKeys[] = $key;
  }
}

print_r($maxKeys);
/*
  Array
  (
      [0] => b
      [1] => c
  )
*/
```